# what is "value" used in @Service annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

What is the diff between these

```
@Service(value="test1")

@Service("test1")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no difference, but if the annotation would take more than one parameter, and you wanted to use more than one parameter, you'd need to use the "value="-syntax. For the usage of the parameter, see the [@Service](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html)-javadoc, or just take a look at the annotation class:

```
public @interface Service {

    /**
     * The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name,
     * to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.
     * @return the suggested component name, if any
     */
    String value() default "";

}
```

The reason why it's called "value" and why you can omit it can be found from [Java annotations documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html):

> It is permissible to omit the element
>   name and equals sign (=) in a
>   single-element annotation whose
>   element name is value